# Symmetry of the non-degenerate ground state

Tags: quantum-mechanics, symmetry, ground-state

From *Quantum field theory and condenced matter* by Shankar, pp67, he mentioned that

> In normal
> problems, the symmetric state, or more generally the state with eigenvalue unity for the
> symmetry operation, the one invariant under the symmetry operation, will be the unique
> ground state.

> Recall that in the oscillator problem the ground state not only had definite
> parity, it was invariant under parity. Likewise, in the hydrogen atom the ground state not
> only has definite angular momentum, the angular momentum is zero and is invariant under
> rotations.

How to prove this arguement?

What I have noticed is that, in usual lecture, a symmetry operator is a unitary operator $U$ with $UHU^\dagger=H$, where $H$ is the Hamiltonian. So strictly speaking, let $Q=-P$, where $P$ is the Parity operator, then $Q$ is a symmetry operator. But in this case, $Q$ doesn't fit our intuition of operator, as we expect $PV(x)=V(-x)$. Also, the ground state is **not** invariant under $Q$, which **is** a symmetry operator by usual definition.

So, I guess the question is how to define a "good" symmetry operator in the first place.

Comment: Regarding the quote from Shankar: Unique with respect to what?!

Comment: You never defined Q. Parity P is a good symmetry operator, as it preserves the 3D Coulomb potential, and hence the Hamiltonian as well.  Specify what you are asking.

Comment: @TobiasFünke I think it means the ground state is not degenerate. ie, unique up to a common factor

Comment: @CosmasZachos symmetry operators are defined on the Hilbert space where quantum state lives, rather than on the real space. So it is reasonable to add a phase factor after the transformation.

Comment: But what if you have degenerate ground states?!

Comment: @TobiasFünke Well, take infinite double well as an example, if the ground state is degenerated, then there will be a even and a odd ground state. I think you can get easy access to such discussion, as many popular textbook has already discussed it, for example Sakurai, 2ed, chapter4.

Comment: Well, he is *defining* "normal problems" to be the ones with a unique vacuum, so no SSB!

Comment: @CosmasZachos What is SSB.

Comment: Spontaneous symmetry breaking : degenerate vacuum.

Comment: Then here is the problem, why unique ground state implies such state has unit eigenvalue for the symmetry operator?@CosmasZachos